# Chrome Extension. Background JS, AJAX Requests, DNS Lookup and SSL handshake Times

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a background script that makes repeated AJAX requests to an Amazon S3 storage bucket.

I've noticed that each time a new request is made to a different object in the same bucket, the background script is having to wait for the DNS lookup (~50ms) and SSL handshake (~80ms).

For some reason I cannot identify, the background script has no memory that it has made previous requests to the same Amazon S3 server / bucket.

I have tried to solve this by adding a preconnect link to the top of the background page - this has no effect. Pinging it with a head request will not actually save me any time.

Any ideas from Chrome Extension wizards?

Comment: Sounds like a quirk/bug in Chrome. Is it any different when performed from a web page? A content script? A visible extension page?

Comment: I was hoping you might be around. Just checked - it's the same from a visible extension page. Each new Ajax request does the handshake. Maybe what I need is a reusable Ajax object.

Comment: Preconnect works in visible extension page.